# How to add more value to existing class (wordpress)?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, class, addition

I need to add 'wsqmylogin' to existing class.
I trired the following codes, but they all don't add it.
Would you please let me know how to solve this problem?
Existing Code (created by plugin YITH):

```
<form id="yith-ywraq-default-form">
     <p class="form-row " id="message_field" data-priority="">
          <textarea name="message" class="input-text " id="message" placeholder=""></textarea>
    </p>
</form>
```

I tried:

```
jQuery('#yith-ywraq-default-form #message_field textarea[class="input-text"]').each(function()
{ this.setAttribute('class', 'wsqmylogin'); });
```

```
jQuery("#yith-ywraq-default-form #message_field textarea").prop("classs","wsqmylogin");
```

```
jQuery("#yith-ywraq-default-form #message_field  .input-text").prop("wsqmylogin")
```

Thank you.

Comment: Run `jQuery('#yith-ywraq-default-form #message_field textarea[class="input-text"]').length` on console ? Did you able to find markup ?

Comment: Hi: Thank you for your comment. I tried it, and it shows 1. Would you let me know what step do I have to take?

Comment: See below answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Dont use `-` in your class name.
2. `id` must be unique so dont use `id` when iterate over each text box. Use `class`.
3. If you have only 1 `textarea` no need to iterate, just catch DOM element and apply your css.
4. `setAttribute` replace your whole previous class so if you want to add new class just use `addClass`

```js
jQuery('#yith-ywraq-default-form .form-row textarea[class="inputtext"]').each(function() {
  this.setAttribute('class', 'inputtext wsqmylogin');
  //jQuery(this).addClass('inputtext wsqmylogin');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="yith-ywraq-default-form">
  <p class="form-row" id="message_field" data-priority="">
    <textarea name="message" class="inputtext" id="message" placeholder=""></textarea>
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Shree: oh, I see, thank you a lot for your explanation and help : ) ... The existing code is created by plugin. I'm a newbie so I don't have the skill to build the code hehe ...